# CVS checkout based only on tags

Tags: cvs

I have a file containing a number of tags contained in a a CVS repository.  Is there a way I can checkout all the files and their associated directories using only these tags without checking out the whole repository?

I don't have a list of the directories in the repository so I can't run `cvs co -r baz_1_0_0_0 foo/bar/baz` since I don't know where `baz` is actually located.

I am running CVS 1.11 so I don't have commands like `rls` available.

Comment: As written, this doesn't make a lot of sense. When you check out using `-r TAG`, you'll only get the files that have that tag. What are you seeing instead?

Comment: Running `cvs co -r baz_1_0_0_0` I get an error that I must `specify at least one module or directory`.  Since what I am checking out is not a module I would need to specify a directory, but I don't know the directory ahead of time and I haven't been able to come up with a way to parse out the needed directories from some other command.

Comment: Well, yes, you have to specify the name of a project. How do you checkout without a tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you do a:

```
   cvs history -T
```

it will give you tags and associated modules (assuming you have CVSROOT defined). 
You can then grep for the TAG you are looking for and checkout only those modules.

e.g.

```
mods=`cvs history -T | grep $TAG | awk '{print $6}'`
for mod in $mods; do
   cvs co -r $TAG $mod
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out `.`. That gives you all the files in the repository. With `-r`, that checks out all the files with that revision or tag.

Note that checking out `.` populates the current directory, so you may want to create a toplevel directory first.

```
mkdir baz
cd baz
cvs co -r baz_1_0_0_0 .
```